# Shang-Chi Leaves particles animation

Tags: animation, modifiers, geometry-nodes, particles, effects

I wanted to create a similar Shang-Chi leaves movement for my shortfilm, can anyone suggest any similar tutorials or ideas to create this effect with blender. Thanks for advance!

Link to HD video : https://youtu.be/9wScpW1ciiE?t=81

[image]

Comment: The question in my opinion is a little broad. But anyways, the best thing that I can think of is using guides. And for that there are many existing resources available on the internet. JUst search for "blender particle guides" for example. You will find many videos regarding that on youtube only!